# Element gets overwriten by value with state

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use the values of data in testVideos, but since it is this.state.data it overwrites my this.state.data value when I make changes to testVideos.

How can I make testVideos independent but using the data from this.state.data so this.state.data doesn't get the same result as testVideos?

```
            try {
              if (dic.length == 99) {
                for (i in dic2) {
                  dic.push(dic2[i])
                }

                //HERE IS WHERE THE OVERWRITE OCCURS 
                const testVideos = this.state.data
                for (const i in testVideos) {
                  for(const j in dic) {
                    if (testVideos[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId == dic[j].id) {
                      testVideos[i].views = dic[j].views
                    }
                  }
                }
                //NOW this.state.data HAS THE SAME VALUE AS testVideos
                //testVideos and this.state.data should have different values
                this.setState({
                  videosWithViews: testVideos.slice(0,10),
                  videoIdDuplicate: true
                })
              }
            } catch(err) {
              console.log("catch")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by treating the objects as immutable (meaning unable to have their properties changed).

Instead of assigning to the `views` property of `testVideos[i]`, you could create a shallow copy of the video object, with the new value set:

```js
testVideos[i] = {
  ...testVideos,
  views: dic[j].views,
}
```

You will also need to create a copy of the array when you assign testVideos.

```js
const testVideos = this.state.data
```